# View pager Fragment is blank on back pressed

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I'm using ViewPager inside fragment. The viewpager contains two fragments.
My problem when I go back to this fragment i got a blank fragment (it works only in the first time).

[image]

ViewPager Code :

```
 private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragment(new ListeMagasinsFragment(), getActivity().getString(R.string.liste));
    adapter.addFragment(new MapMagasinsFragment(), getActivity().getString(R.string.carte));
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

I also overrided onBackPressed() :

```
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        } else {
            getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }
        //super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

This code below shows the fragment transaction :

```
 Fragment fragment = new MagasinDetailsFragment();
                    if (fragment != null) {
                        Bundle bundles = new Bundle();

                        if (magasin != null) {
                            bundles.putSerializable("magasin", (Serializable) magasin);
                            Log.e("magasin", "is valid");
                        } else {
                            Log.e("magasin", "is null");
                        }
                        fragment.setArguments(bundles);

                        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();


                    }
```

More code:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_magasins, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
    viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


    setupViewPager(viewPager);

    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

}
```

Fragment xml :

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
        android:id="@+id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:tabMaxWidth="0dp"
        app:tabMode="fixed"
        app:tabGravity="fill"/>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"  />
```

main_activity.xml :

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"
    />
```

And content_main.xml :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.carrefour.creova.carrefourmobile.activities.MainActivity"
tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_main">
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/container_body"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     />
```

Any ideas ?

Comment: Remove the line fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null); and then check

Comment: Please also add code where you start/inflate your viewpager.

Comment: If I remove it I can't go back to previous fragment and when the back button is pressed the app is closed

Comment: @Okas :  viewPager = (ViewPager)view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);


        setupViewPager(viewPager);

        tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

Comment: @Rockers23 - more please, in your snippet viewpager is already inflated (and you get a reference to it with findviewbyid).

Comment: try changing `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0` to `getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 1`

Comment: @Okas : I don't understand what you want exactly.  You need xml or viewpager adapter ?

Comment: @FabinPaul : Now nothing happen when back button is pressed.

Comment: @Rockers23 - i'd like to see where viewPager is inflated, this is probably in onCreate of some Activity or onCreateView of some fragment.

Comment: @Okas : I edited my post

Comment: Sry, but fragment_magasins.xml could also be useful. :) Btw - you are adding fragment_magasins in code, not inflating from xml?

Comment: I added it to my post

Comment: Please post also your activity layout xml - ie the root of all these things.

Comment: Done. One more info,I'm using navigation Drawer so I also posted content main xml.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130104/discussion-between-okas-and-rockers23).

Answer (score 0):

In your Activity override the onBackPressed() method.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() > 0) {
        getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else{
 finish();
            }
        }
```

You must have added the fragments to the BackStack for this to work, something similar to:

```
Fragment fragment = new YourFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("variable_if_needed", "Some Value");
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.relativecontent, fragment)
            .addToBackStack(null)
            .commit();
    return true;
```

"R.id.relativecontent" should be your Fragment container.
Is it actually necessary to go back to the previous page in the viewPager when you press the back button? That is not something I have seen often. For one, the previous page(Fragment) should be a left or right swipe away from the current one, and you may implement an AlertDialog to prompt the user to see if he wants to exit the app instead.

Comment: I already did that and nothing changed. I will add an AlertDialog thx :)